# split one object into multiple objects based on the property

Tags: javascript

```
myObj = {1-inputWidth : '30px' , 1-inputHeight: '30px', 1-color : 'red',
        2-inputWidth : '20px' , 2-inputHeight: '10px', 2-color : 'blue',
        3-inputWidth : '60px' , 3-inputHeight: '70px', 3-color : 'white',  
        4-inputWidth : '90px' , 4-inputHeight: '10px', 4-color :'yellow', 
        scroll : 'auto', z-index : 1}
```

```
resultObj = {1: {1-inputWidth : '30px' , 1-inputHeight: '30px', 1-color : 'red'},
             2: { 2-inputWidth : '20px' , 2-inputHeight: '10px', 2-color : 'blue'}, 
             3: {3-inputWidth : '60px' , 3-inputHeight: '70px', 3-color : 'white'},  
             4: {4-inputWidth : '90px' , 4-inputHeight: '10px', 4-color :'yellow'}}
```

I am having an object where most of the keys starting with a number and few doesnt. I am looking to remove those keys which are not starting with a number like scroll and z-index and also make a nested object with keys as numbers matching with the intial key number. This actually messed with my head. Could anyone suggest me how to acheive this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any rationale behind objects with numeric indices? You might be interested in an array for this task.

Comment: you can use reduce function to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iteratee through your `Object.entries` and look at each key with a regex to see if it starts with a number. If so, add it to the appropriate subobject:

```js
let myObj = {'1-inputWidth' : '30px' , '1-inputHeight': '30px', '1-color' : 'red','2-inputWidth' : '20px' , '2-inputHeight': '10px', '2-color' : 'blue','3-inputWidth' : '60px' , '3-inputHeight': '70px', '3-color' : 'white',  '4-inputWidth' : '90px' , '4-inputHeight': '10px', '4-color' :'yellow', scroll : 'auto', 'z-index' : 1}

let o = Object.entries(myObj)
       .reduce((obj, [k, v]) => {
          let num = k.match(/^\d+/)              // get number in key?
          if (num) {                             // was there a match?
              if (obj[num]) obj[num][k] = v      // add new entry
              else obj[num] = {[k]: v}
          }
          return obj

       }, {})

console.log(o)
```

Comment: Thank you! Got the result as i am expecting.